# Will trigger fire when cross object fields update?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written Trigger on Object 1 and I am manually updating a field on Object 2 which will automatically update one field on Object 1. So will trigger fire when the field in Object 1 is updated?

When i am manually updating on Object 1, trigger on Object 1 is executing and I am able to see logs. But when I am updating a field on Object 2, Trigger on Object 1 is not executing and not getting any logs.

Can any one suggest me will trigger fire when cross object field update?

Comment: Check if this Link is useful - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, it should fire always, can you post the code in order to get it understand better

Comment: What type of field is updated on Object 1 from Object 2? If that is a formula, actually not data is changed on Object 2, and no trigger will fire for that.

Comment: The field type which i am updating on Object 1 is CheckBox. Field   Name id IsPrimay. So Trigger on Object 1 will update Address with Parent Object's Address (Not object 2) when IsPrimary changed to True.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to show, how the update is done and the code for the trigger you expect to be running.

Comment: If Object2's trigger does DML on Object1, the triggers on Object1 will execute